# What would be the most efficient way of implementing a dark mode in my application?

Tags: ios, swift, themes

I have an application that I want to shift to night mode when a button is pressed. What would be the best way of doing that?
I was thinking of creating a class of light vs dark colors to use for certain labels as well as a notification firing when the button is pressed to notify all of the app to adopt the colors. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to set the color, you need to set the properties tintColor or barTintColor or something like this. But I think the real question of yours is, how you can effectifly switch between the two modes.
Your idea with the theme manager class that fires a notification is not that bad, another option would be to observe for theme changes. But firing a notification might be even better.
In this case you only need to listen for the theme-changed-notification inside you UI-subclasses and change their color if the notification fires. And don't forget to remove the NSNotificationCenter-observer in your dealloc :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a web application you can use only CSS to implement a light- switch function.

This [page](http://designshack.net/articles/css/lightsoff/) looks exactly what you are looking for.

(It also has a CodePen demo.)